# How to make background image size responsive to desktop and mobile?

Tags: css, html

I'd like to have a background image on my homepage that is full width on desktop, but as the screen size shrinks, less and less of the right hand side of the image should disappear (but always shows the left hand edge and the objects in the left hand of the image).

The CSS code I have for this is as follows;

```
.sm-img-bg-fullscr {
  background-position: 0% 0px;
  background-size:auto;

  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

and the html where this class is called is as follows;

```
<div class="sm-img-bg-fullscr parallax-section" style="background-image: url(assets/system/backgroundimage.jpg)" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
```

I have tried adjusting the background-size variables, and the background position variable, but with no luck. The image being used is 1920 x 1080.

I would like to know what combination of CSS parameters will allow the full image to be shown when the screen width is large enough, and have it remove more and more of the right hand side of the image as the screen size is narrowed, making only the left hand side of the image visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use media queries to adjust the image background on certain screen sizes?

All we are doing is adjusting the `background-position`.

```css
body {
margin: 0; padding: 0}

*{
box-sizing:border-box}

.image {
  width:100vw;
  height:100vw;
  background-image:url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/94/Cirrus_clouds_mar08.jpg");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center center;
  background-size: cover
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1px) and (max-width:700px) {
  .image {
    background-position:left center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="image">

</div>
```

Comment: I found that the use of width:100% was preventing the image from aligning to left center even when the size conditional code was added. When I removed this and used height = 100% instead, it seems to align left center as it should - but I'd like to understand why this is for future reference - do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Di you tried this?

```
background-position: center;
```

Comment: I have tried this - it does not appear to have any effect different to the use of background-position: 50% 0% which I have also tried. Thanks, though!

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your CSS

```
{background-size: auto;}
```

or try inline style using `max-width: ??.px`